# is there a Google Map URL parameter for hide side panel?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, url-parameters

I have used many google map parameters like

- q=
- near=
- f=
- saddr=
- daddr=

but what I want is hide the side panel. is there a way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such option(basically none of these parameters is officially documented).

But setting the `output`-parameter to `embed` will have the desired effect(but will remove the search-bar too)

https://maps.google.co.uk/?output=embed

Comment: If you try to do this straight to a browser window, it comes up with the error `The Google Maps Embed API must be used in an iframe.`